# selenium webDriver (Firefox) : connection refused

Tags: java, selenium

**Details -**

constantnly getting error "**HttpHostConnectException :Connect to localhost:27364" on server**.

On my local machine there is no issue but in server it throws error "Connection Refused"

i am tried the solutions but getting error

**Environment details -**
1.Selenium jar version  - 3.6
2.Geckodriver jar version  - 0.19
3.Browser version : Firefox 62

**Error -** 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.**HttpHostConnectException**: Connect to localhost:27364 [localhost/127.0.0.1] **failed: Connection refused** (Connection refused)
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:40.131Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-7-107.ec2.internal', ip: '172.31.7.107', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-1060-aws', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Comment: This is not a duplicate question

Comment: Can you help me to understand how the error which you are facing as `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException` is different from the dup marked discussion on `WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException Connection Refused`

Comment: Hi i wrote the selenium script for file downloading from mail but it through the error on server machine but it can't on local machine

Comment: Can you update the question with your `selenium script for file downloading from mail` which _through the error on server machine but it can't on local machine_?